# CFChart on railo

Tags: railo, cfchart

I am facing a problem while generating a pdf. I am adding cfchart in the pdf.

Here is my code:

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" localUrl="yes">
<cfchart>
    <cfchartseries type="pie">
        <cfchartdata item="New car sales" value="50000">
        <cfchartdata item="Used car sales" value="25000">
        <cfchartdata item="Leasing" value="30000">
        <cfchartdata item="Service" value="40000">
    </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>
</cfdocument>
```

It is generating blank (white page) pdf. But it's not showing any chart in it.
If i removed the cfdocument tag then it is showing the chart.
The same code works fine if run on Coldfusion server.

Comment: Railo is no longer supported and hasn't been developed for over two year, I would suggest you upgrade to Lucee and try on there. Details on upgrading to Lucee can be found here: http://docs.lucee.org/guides/updating-lucee/migrate-from-railo.html

Comment: I found a solution on a different post here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39133456/1182823