# cfchartseries does not match current parent item cfchart error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfchart

```
<cfchart format="png"  
        backgroundcolor="white" 
        title="My Chart" 
        showxgridlines="false" 
        showygridlines="false" 
        chartwidth="380"
        chartheight="250"
        yaxistitle="(value1)"
        showborder="true"
        gridlines="5"
        showmarkers="no"
        style="../jscript/ApstatBar_vac.js"     
        >
        <cfchartseries serieslabel="title1" type="bar" datalabelstyle="value" seriescolor="##B4B2B2">
            <cfloop index="counter1" from=1 to="#arraylen(xleavles_grph)#" step="1">
                <cfchartdata item="#xleavles_grph[counter1]#" value="#ser1Values_grph[counter1]#" >
            </cfloop>
        </cfchartseries>
        <cfchartseries serieslabel="title2" type="line" datalabelstyle="value" seriescolor="blue">
            <cfloop index="counter1" from=1 to="#arraylen(xleavles_grph)#" step="1">
                <cfchartdata item="" value="#ser2Values_grph[counter1]#" >
            </cfloop>
        </cfchartseries>
```

I am getting the error:

> cfchartseries does not match current parent item cfchart

and thereby the chart is not shown when the page is rendered.

Some help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Worked for me, with the addition of `</cfchart>`. Please post a self contained example that reproduces the error.

Comment: i tried with </cfchart. at the end of the code..it still wont show the chart

Comment: What do you mean "Not showing the chart"? Same error message or the chart isn't visible? Like I said, it worked for me so something is different on your end. You need to create a *self contained* example that produces the error on your end, including sample values.

Comment: @Ageax The chart isn't visible. All i am getting is a small placeholder like square. Here is the link to the image that i receive after running the page      https://imgur.com/a/mPQFu.Everything else other than chart works fine in the page.

Comment: @Ageax. This is more confusing now. At first when i was checking the page i was printing the page as PDF ie <cfdocument format="pdf">, Now for the sake of verifying i just tried commenting the cfdocument tag Now the chart works perfectly.Wonder why it wont work when it is set to be PDF

Comment: "printing the page as PDF" Oh, embedding an image in a PDF is totally different. The missing image / red x just means the engine had problems accessing the chart image.  There's already answers in the archives about that.  Do a search on "embedding cfchart in pdf". This is for <cfhtmltopdf> but the problem is resolved the same way. You could also use cfimage action="writeToBrowser" inside the cfdocument..

Comment: @Ageax.THANKS let me check that

Comment: Sorry, forgot the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600156/cfchart-not-printing-in-pdf